# Background color aswell as background image in the same CSS rule not working

Tags: css

This CSS rule works fine:

```
#selector { 
background: repeat-y transparent 50% url(data:image/png;base64,mybase64encodedimage);
}
```

However this one fails and does nothing. Why is this? I thought that you could specify a background color as well as a background image in the same rule.

```
#selector { 
background: white repeat-y transparent 50% url(data:image/png;base64,mybase64encodedimage);
}
```

Comment: I see two background colors.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that you declare the background color as white but then transparent again. See [this guide](http://www.dustindiaz.com/css-shorthand/) on how the background shorthand works btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnFyX/).

The HTML:

```
<div id="selector">red</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#selector { 
background: red repeat-y /*transparent*/ 50% url(data:image/png;base64,mybase64encodedimage);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to look more like this:

```
#selector { 
background: white repeat-y 50% url(data:image/png;base64,mybase64encodedimage);
}
```

`transparent` is your background color in the first one that is working fine.

So technically what you have done is place 2 background colors onto your `background`: `white` & `transparent` and because `transparent` comes after `white`, it is overriding the former.

Comment: Yes, and because `transparent` comes after `white`, it is overriding the former.